# Tabular Browser Windows for Atom-Shell?

Tags: node.js, electron

I'm playing around with the [atom-shell](https://github.com/atom/atom-shell) and was wondering if anybody has used/written a module for making tubular browser windows?

Currently, it seems, atom-shell opens a completely new window when instantiating a [BrowserWindow](https://github.com/atom/atom-shell/blob/master/docs/api/browser-window.md):

```
var win = new BrowserWindow({ width: 800, height: 600, show: false });
win.on('closed', function() {
  win = null;
});

win.loadUrl('https://github.com');
win.show();
```

Is there a way of tabularising the window, like in the [atom](https://atom.io/) application? Or will I have to write this functionality inside the current BrowserWindow in order to get it to work?

Comment: >[In atom-shell you have to draw tabs and other controls with HTML, there is no plan to implement Chromium like tabs.](https://github.com/atom/atom-shell/issues/556#issuecomment-51556508)

Comment: @laggingreflex Well found. Surprised they don't discuss the subject within the doc pages. Seems like an obvious *missing feature*. If you'd like to move this into an answer, I'll accept.

Comment: I'm actually new to atom-shell myself, and even with chromium that atom-shell uses. I'll let someone more knowledgeable answer authoritatively.

Comment: @laggingreflex Roger that. I have a sneaking suspicion that you're right though

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to create native tabs in Atom Shell. That being said, what @zcbenz suggests is entirely doable with the `<WebView>` tag, which allows you to safely host arbitrary web content inside Atom Shell.

Comment: Are you able to provide a link to where @zcbenz suggests this?

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately there is no detail here about how to implement web views. And as far as I can tell, @zcbenz doesn't confirm/disconfirm the use of a <WebView> tag.